# URL resolution issues in Django Tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-3.x, url-routing

I've written a django model that has a get_absolute_url method, with unit tests to make sure everything is kosher. The get_absolute_url tests pass no problem. The get_absolute_url method is written as so

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("scheduling:klass", args=[self.pk])
```

This is the url routing to give context about how the urls flow.

```
#main.urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', homepage, name="home"),
    url(r'^scheduling/', include('scheduling.urls', namespace="scheduling")),
    url(r'^profile/', include('user_profile.urls', namespace="profile")),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

#scheduling.urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'add-class/$', views.add_klass, name="add_klass"),
    url(r'class/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.klass, name="klass"),
]
```

I'm testing the klass view (it's basically just a klass detail view) as follows

```
def test_klass_detail_template_renders(self):
    print(self.klass.pk)
    response = self.client.get(self.klass.get_absolute_url())
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "scheduling/klass.html")
```

The test fails with the following stacktrace.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_klass_detail_template_renders (scheduling.tests.test_views.KlassViewTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 586, in reverse
    extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]
KeyError: 'myproject.profile'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 507, in render
    current_app=current_app)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 596, in reverse
    key)
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: 'myproject.profile' is not a registered namespace

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Development/myproject/src/scheduling/tests/test_views.py", line 60, in test_klass_detail_template_renders
    response = self.client.get(self.klass.get_absolute_url())
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 503, in get
    **extra)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 304, in get
    return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)

...
    File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 508, in _reverse_with_prefix
        (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
    django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/$', 'profile/(?
    P<username>[\\w+-.@]+)/$']
```

It implies that that get_absolute_url is passing the pk value of the klass model to the url pattern but it works when I test it manually and it works in literally every other situation.

This...is...a...head scratcher. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I think it might have to do with test isolation. I've done some print debugging and found that each test creates a new instance of the klass model.

Here are my setUp and tearDown methods.

```
class KlassViewTests(TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.factory = ClassMateFactory()
    self.teacher = self.factory.create_teacher("Maria")
    self.linked_student = self.factory.create_student(
        "Milhouse",
        self.teacher.profile
    )
    self.klass = self.factory.create_klass(
        "Test Klass",
        teachers=self.teacher.profile,
        students=self.linked_student.profile
    )
    self.data = {
        "name": "New Test Class",
        "status": "A",
        "students": [self.linked_student.profile.pk],
        "teachers": [self.teacher.profile.pk]
    }
    super().setUp()

def tearDown(self):
    print(self.klass.get_absolute_url())
    self.teacher.delete()
    self.linked_student.delete()
    self.klass.delete()
    super().tearDown()
```

Hopefully this helps clear things up.

**EDIT**

Added the url conf to provide more context

Comment: Do you mean `response = self.client.get(self.klass.get_absoule_url())`??

Comment: It would work out to the same thing basically, since when you pass a model instance to reverse it calls the get_absolute_url method on the model. For completeness though I tried your code...came out with a different (much uglier) stack trace but with the same error.

Comment: I am not sure what you mention about passing a model instance to `reverse` call is true. If you look at the error it clearly mentions that `NoReverseMatch` for `Test Klass`. What I understand from this is that `Test Klass` is the string representation of your class and since you passed an object `reverse` thinks that you have directly passed the view instead of view name.

Comment: What errors are you getting when you tried my suggestion?

Comment: You're right about reverse(). I had confused it with redirect() which you can pass a model instance. That being said even with your self.klass.get_absolute_url() code it didn't work. I've added the newer stack trace to the question.

Comment: Can you also add the implementation of the test which is failing. Because the one you added earlier has a different name than the one which is failing.

Comment: I've been looking at the stack trace and it appears that theres a conflict with the url resolver and it's trying to resolve using another namespace that I had declared (profile). If needed I'll be able to provide more info. Feel free to ask.

Comment: That was my mistake...I had tweaked the test name while I was writing (not smart). I've amended it to prevent any further confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108136/discussion-between-guptam-and-aks).

Answer (score 1):

With the current state of your question it looks like a copy paste error. Why I think this:

The error is described by Django as:

```
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch:
Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
2 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/$', 'profile/(?P<username>[\\w+-.@]+)/$']
```

You have omitted part of the stack trace so I cannot be sure but the line that causes this error in your code is:

```
response = self.client.get(self.klass.get_absolute_url())
```

The model in question seems not to be `profile` but something called `klass`.

*Seems*...

It could also be that `self.klass` at this point actually refers to a profile (of a teacher or student) and that is why it uses the `profile`'s `get_absolute_url`.

tl;dr I think you just need to thoroughly read through all of your code (maybe get some second pair of eyes) to find the little mistypings.

Comment: It would seem to be a copy and paste error but I don't think it is. I have basically a full test suite for this project currently and the only failures I currently have are in this test and another test that tests this view (it has almost the exact same stack trace). Since the code seems to work properly when run manually I think it must be a problem in the implementation of the test. Would you like to see the entire stack trace?

Comment: The obvious difference to regular usage is that you are not using the database (fixtures) but creating the model instances via this `ClassMateFactory`. I never do it like that, I simply define test fixtures to make Django run as close to real as possible. Django's test suite sets up a test database and removes it after the tests so no fear of corrupting your real data.

Comment: Oh I guess that's a difference of opinion. I prefer using factories to generate objects because I don't like maintaining fixtures. I would use [FactoryBoy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org) but I don't think the scope of my project needs it just yet. That said...I don't see how switching to fixtures would solve this situation.

Comment: Any other suggestions @Risadinha? I'm stuck on this since I don't really want to be playing with a non-functioning test suite.